# Implicit conversion of float to int and possibility of loss of value

Tags: c

I'm learning about data-types in C.

Our course material details as follows

> When we assign different variables of different data-types, there is a
> possibility of loss of value.

```
float f = 100.6537;
int i = f;
```

After execution of above code, `i = 100`. So correct me if I'm wrong, assigning float to int just chops of fractional value and assigns only the integral value to left of decimal point? and loss of value here being the removal of numbers after decimal point ?

But when I do,

```
int i = 100;
float f = i;
```

I think that there is no loss of value here ?

Comment: Yeah, it is in this particular case.

Comment: Yes, your thinking is correct on both cases. Note that there can be a loss in going from integral to a float also, if the float type can’t handle the precision of the integral type. For example, 32but floats usually have around 7 digits of precision so writing 123456789 into one loses accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every `int` can be represented as a `float`. The `float` lacks enough "places" to represent all possible values. Remember, `sizeof(int)==sizeof(float)` on many machines. In [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format you only get 24 bits of "value" in a `float`.

In other words:

```
int   = snnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
float = seeeeeeeennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

Where the `e` part is the exponent. Note how the `int` has a lot more bits to represent the numerical value.

For anything that fits neatly in a 24 bit number you should be fine, but it's worth testing on your hardware to be sure.

Comment: So in case of int, I have 32 bits to represent a number, while only 24 bits in case of a float to represent mantissa ? Which means the max value = (2^24 - 1) can be represented in float without loss of value, right?

Comment: In rough terms, yes. Technically you can squeak out a few more values that are even powers, but that's a little awkward since the powers are expressed in base 2. You could use `double` which can handle the full range, it has 53 bits of "significand".